# Center align a <p> tag with <select>

Tags: html, css

In redesigning a simple survey page I am facing a minor problem. Just like all the other elements, I want to centre-align p tag with select tag. I am able to centre align them, without display:flex inside .combobox class but I want them to be in the same line and still centre-align them.

My present layout is like this:
[image: Layout]

To summarise, I want to centre the Select and Combobox.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color: rgb(56, 65, 77);
  color: white;
  padding: 3%;
  font-size: 200%;
}

section {
  color: rgb(56, 65, 77);
  border-style: none;
}

.combobox {
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
}

fieldset {
  border: none;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgb(56, 65, 77);
  color: white;
  padding: 1%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

select {
  margin-top: 14px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header>SURVEY.COM</header>
<form method="POST">
  <section>
    <h1>Submit your Survey Today!</h1>
    <p>Your Name</p>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <p>Your Email</p>
    <input type="text" id="email">
    <div class="combobox">
      <p>Select</p>
      <select name="cars" id="cars">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>What is Your Favorite Pet?</legend>
      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" value="Cats">Cats
      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" value="Dogs">Dogs
      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" value="Birds">Birds
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit now" />
  </section>
</form>

<footer>
  Copyright &copy; 2021
</footer>
```

Comment: `.combobox { justify-content: center; }`

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you very much, this worked. Can you please explain why this is needed? For other tags, I haven't used it. Thanks

Comment: It's part of the flexbox set of standards: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Answer (score 0):

you can do this simply with css:

```
select#cars {
    text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ma0vwhj9/
updated example

Comment: This doesn't work. I tried it.

Comment: check now the jsfiddle updated, and consider to make a cleaner version of your html, is totally not responsive

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to make this responsive once I get stronger grip on CSS.